# List view asList not recognised by android studio

Tags: java, android, listview

Building a list View and from the code below used to work but as highlighted my asList is not recognised by Java. Can some body tell me where I have gone wrong. This was working on previous android studio version but not now?

```
package com.example.air rocketapps.listviewdemo;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import java.util.ArrayList;

    import static java.util.Arrays.asList;


    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            ListView friendsListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.friendsListView);

            final ArrayList<String> myFriends = new ArrayList<String>(**asList**("John", "Paul", "George", "Ringo"));

            ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myFriends);

            friendsListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

            friendsListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hello " + myFriends.get(position), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: are you using these stars?  ** asList **

Comment: No this was to highlight the asList so you could easily find the piece of code I was talking about

Comment: Can you tell me exactly what error message is displaying by Android studio ?

Answer (score 1):

`Arrays.asList()` is a Fabric method so you should NOT use `new ArrayList` with it
Just use 
`final ArrayList<String> myFriends = Arrays.asList("John", "Paul", "George", "Ringo"));`

Update: it's better to use interface in left side of assigment i.e.

final **List** < String> myFriends

Comment: While I agree with your advice, the code he has should actually work

Answer (score 0):

There is no Activity.asList() function.  There's an Arrays.asList() function.  That's probably what you meant.

Comment: He is importing it: `import static java.util.Arrays.asList;`

Comment: Ugh.  Static imports should be removed from the language-  they only cause confusion.

Answer (score -1):

I create like this and it work

```
final ArrayList<String> myfamily = new ArrayList<String>(asList(new String[]{"Rob","Tommy","Ben","Charly"}));
```

Answer (score -1):

I created like this and it work.
final List myFriends = Arrays.asList("John","Jane","Anuj","Biubiu");

Comment: Please use proper formatting to help us understand it quickly. Try to answer the question by referring to its bits and specifying a possible solution.